# How to return a boolean method in java?

Tags: java, function, methods, boolean

I need help on how to return a boolean method in java. This is the sample code:

```
public boolean verifyPwd(){
        if (!(pword.equals(pwdRetypePwd.getText()))){
                  txtaError.setEditable(true);
                  txtaError.setText("*Password didn't match!");
                  txtaError.setForeground(Color.red);
                  txtaError.setEditable(false);
           }
        else {
            addNewUser();
        }
        return //what?
}
```

I want the `verifyPwd()` to return a value on either true or false whenever I want to call that method. I want to call that method like this:

```
if (verifyPwd()==true){
    //do task
}
else {
    //do task
}
```

How to set the value for that method?

Comment: Why the downvote for a perfectly valid question that may be helpful to others who are starting to learn?

Comment: who knows what do you want to return for what situation?....

Comment: Since nobody mentioned that: The `== true` part is pointless. The method returns a `boolean` already, so `if(verifyPwd())` is perfectly valid `if` statement. It is also perfectly readable if the method name is chosen carefully to result in a nice sentence like `if(passwordRetypeMatches())`.

Comment: Also, I'd avoid using so much logic in a method that only has verification or matching in its name: Such logic should be done outside, most likely in the if-else branches.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're allowed to have more than one `return` statement, so it's legal to write

```
if (some_condition) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

It's also unnecessary to compare boolean values to `true` or `false`, so you can write

```
if (verifyPwd())  {
  // do_task
}
```

---

Edit: Sometimes you can't return early because there's more work to be done.  In that case you can declare a boolean variable and set it appropriately inside the conditional blocks.

```
boolean success = true;

if (some_condition) {
  // Handle the condition.
  success = false;
} else if (some_other_condition) {
  // Handle the other condition.
  success = false;
}
if (another_condition) {
  // Handle the third condition.
}

// Do some more critical things.

return success;
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
public boolean verifyPwd(){
        if (!(pword.equals(pwdRetypePwd.getText()))){
                  txtaError.setEditable(true);
                  txtaError.setText("*Password didn't match!");
                  txtaError.setForeground(Color.red);
                  txtaError.setEditable(false);
                  return false;
           }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        
}

if (verifyPwd()==true){
    addNewUser();
}
else {
    // passwords do not match
```

System.out.println("password do not match");
}

Comment: I know it was in his original code, but there's no reason to have an `else` when the `if` block ended with `return`, and there's no need to compare a boolean value with true.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean verifyPwd(){
        if (!(pword.equals(pwdRetypePwd.getText()))){
                  txtaError.setEditable(true);
                  txtaError.setText("*Password didn't match!");
                  txtaError.setForeground(Color.red);
                  txtaError.setEditable(false);
                  return false;
           }
        else {
            addNewUser();
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this, for readability's sake

```
boolean passwordVerified=(pword.equals(pwdRetypePwd.getText());

if(!passwordVerified ){
    txtaError.setEditable(true);
    txtaError.setText("*Password didn't match!");
    txtaError.setForeground(Color.red);
    txtaError.setEditable(false);
}else{
    addNewUser();
}
return passwordVerified;
```

Comment: @JayMarz what is recursive?

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to declare `Boolean` variable within the code block and `return` it at end of code, like this:

```
public boolean Test(){
    boolean booleanFlag= true; 
    if (A>B)
    {booleanFlag= true;}
    else 
    {booleanFlag = false;}
    return booleanFlag;

}
```

I find this the best way.